# Is there a way to get rid of all the other characters not in the " "s in python?

Tags: python

Let's say I wanted to strip this string "Tell Cassy, 'Baloney is cool!' okay?" How do I strip out everything other than the characters in the ' ', to make the string into "'Baloney is cool!'"?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Finding tags and the text between is solved in many places on line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using splicing.

```
x = "Tell Cassy, 'Baloney is cool!' okay?"
print(x.split("'")[1])
```

We will split the string at `'` then take the second element in the returned list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `string split` method as follows:

```
mystr= "Tell Cassy, 'Baloney is cool!' okay?"
a=mystr.split(' ')
str=' '
print(str.join(a[2:5]))
```

This gives the following output:

```
'Baloney is cool!'
```